# why i can't get my value in the select in PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, select

i'm practicing on how to use the select in the php, but why i can't display my value in my select box here in php? i'm using a codeigniter framework and here is my folder structure

- controllers

  - Category.php
- models

  - Model_category.php
- views

  - category

    - index.php

the code in the index.php was

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="active">From Category:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="active" name="active">
            <?php foreach ($category as $k => $v): ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>"><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
      </div>
```

and then i have this in controllers in Category.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->not_logged_in();
    
    $this->data['page_title'] = 'Category';
    $this->load->model('model_category');
}


public function index()
    {
        $this->render_template('category/index', $this->data);
        $category['getCategoryData'] = $this->model_category >getCategoryData();
        //print_r($category);die;
        //$this->load->view('category/index', $category);
    }
```

my table name is "category" and it's row is id,name,active

i tried this

```
$category = $this->model_category->getCategoryData();$this->load- >view('category/index', $category);
```

and it's working when i print using this

```
print_r($category);die;
```

output:

```
Array ( [getCategoryData] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 
[name] => Adds On [active] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] 
=> Meals [active] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => 
Drinks [active] => 1 ) ) )
```

but i still can't display it in the select box, when i add the load view it will return like this DataTables warning: table id=manageTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

my portion of code in ajax in the category.php:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#FileMainNav").addClass('active');
  $('#categoryMainNav').addClass('active');
  // initialize the datatable 
  manageTable = $('#manageTable').DataTable({
    'ajax': base_url + 'category/fetchCategoryData',
    'order': []
  });

  // submit the create from 
  $("#createForm").unbind('submit').on('submit', function() {
    var form = $(this);

    // remove the text-danger
    $(".text-danger").remove();

    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: form.attr('method'),
      data: form.serialize(), // /converting the form data into array and sending it to server
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(response) {

        manageTable.ajax.reload(null, false); 

        if(response.success === true) {
          $("#messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
            '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
          '</div>');
```

Comment: In your controller you are not passing "your chosen category" to the view.

Comment: how can i pass it @talha2k

Comment: Can you show the function which loads your view with the select box?

Comment: @talha2k i think i do not have the function that's why I'm having trouble any chance you can show me the way to create the function which load the view with select box?

Comment: add this function in your controller:

public function index()
    {
        $data['category'] = "Your_chosen_category_ID";
        $this->load->view('page_with_select_box', $data);
    }

Comment: @talha2k i tried this   $category = $this->model_category->getCategoryData();$this->load->view('category/index', $category);
 and it's working when i print using this print_r($category);die; but i still can't display it in the select box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248883/discussion-between-wloleo-and-talha2k).

Comment: I'd suggest you read through [CI 3.x form helper](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html), particularly [form_dropdown()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_dropdown). Since you are using a framework, take advantage of it.

Comment: Check your browser error console. It looks like you have a DataTables error which is preventing the data from being displayed (not a direct PHP error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this example can help you:
(Codeigniter v 3.1.13)

Model:

```
class Category_model extends CI_Model
{
  public function all()
   {
    $query = $this->db->get('category');
    return $query->result();
   }
 }
```

Controller:

```
class Category extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Category_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $data['category'] = $this->category_model->all();
            $this->load->view('category/index', $data);
    }

 }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="active">From Category:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="active" name="active">
        <?php foreach ($category as $items): ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $items->id ?>"><?php echo  $items->name ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
  </div>
```

UPDATE:

To use Datatables on Codeigniter you can make a method like this:
[Source](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/44562/datatables-1-10-with-codeigniter-3-1-5)

```
public function get_json($aTable = NULL, $aColumns = NULL)
{

    // Read dataTables POST variables
    $iDraw = $this->input->post('draw');
    $iColumns = $this->input->post('columns');
    $iOrder = $this->input->post('order');
    $iStart = $this->input->post('start');
    $iLength = $this->input->post('length');
    $iSearch = $this->input->post('search');

    // Total rows in the table
    $recordsTotal = $this->db->count_all($aTable);

    // Filtering
    // NOTE: This does not match the built-on DataTables filtering which does it
    // word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
    // on very large tables.
    $recordsFiltered = $recordsTotal;

    if (isset($iSearch) && $iSearch['value'] != '') {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
            $this->db->or_like($aColumns[$i], $iSearch['value']);
        }

        // Saves number of records that matches the query and filters
        $recordsFiltered = $this->db->count_all_results($aTable, false);
    }

    if (isset($iSearch) && $iSearch['value'] != '') {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
            $this->db->or_like($aColumns[$i], $iSearch['value']);
        }
    }

    // Write the SELECT portion of the query
    $this->db->select(implode(',', $aColumns));

    // Ordering
    if (isset($iOrder)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($iOrder); $i++) {
            $this->db->order_by($aColumns[$iOrder[0]['column']], strtoupper($iOrder[0]['dir']));
        }
    } else {
        $this->db->order_by($aColumns[0], 'ASC');
    }

    // Paging
    if (isset($iStart) && $iLength != '-1') {
        $this->db->limit($iLength, $iStart);
    } else {
        $this->db->limit(25, 1);
    }

    // Select Data
    $Data = $this->db->get($aTable);

    // JSON enconding
    $json = json_encode(array(
            "draw" => isset($iDraw) ? $iDraw : 1,
            "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal,
            "recordsFiltered" => $recordsFiltered,
            "data" => $Data->result())
    );

    return $json;
}
```

Comment: i'm having a "DataTables warning: table id=manageTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. "

Comment: my index has a render templete and when i add the load view it returns cannot reinitialise data table, public function index()
 {
  $this->render_template('subcat/index', $this->data);
  $data['category'] = $this->model_category->all();
        $this->load->view('category/index', $data);
  
 

 }

Comment: Do you want to use datatable in Codeigniter?

Comment: @Shamarasy yes, my ajax in on the top

Comment: I suggest making a library to load your data from the database

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/44562/datatables-1-10-with-codeigniter-3-1-5

Comment: why i'm having a Message:  Undefined variable $category

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: the whole program? how

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248907/discussion-between-wloleo-and-shahmarasy).